# What is this type of wire-connector called?

Tags: connector, wire

I am having the hardest time finding something like this on Mouser. I have find things similar, without the screw for example, but never exactly this. Is there a generic name for this type of connector? 
If you type something like PCB 2 Way Connector into Google then your search is through, but Mouser apparently has a different naming convention for these little connectors.

This is the closest thing I could find, but I either need a 4-way connector or a 2-way. Ideally I would like to find the same connectors as shown below.

[image]

Examples:

[Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DSKC6TW)

[Another Website](https://www.robotics.org.za/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=508)

Comment: I usually call it a 'screw terminal'

Comment: Note that these things slide together with a dovetail, so you can simply push two 2's together to make a 4. With 2's and 3's you can make pretty much any reasonable size terminal block.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go hundreds of them:
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/OSTTA020161/ED2561-ND/614512
http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/terminal-blocks-wire-to-board/1442751?k=screw%20terminal

Comment: Perfect. I was only finding din-rail and other similar items when I searched for something like "terminal block".